# What is the equivalence class of the number 2 when the relation takes two inputs?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations, foundations

I have the following relation T on $N\times N$ given by $(a, b)T(c, d)$ if $a + b = c + d$. The question is to find the equivalence class of the number 2. However, I'm confused as the relation takes pairs of numbers. Is it possible? Do we find all combination of a and b that add to 2? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I agree with you that the question is not clear.  The relation is between pairs of natural numbers, not single natural numbers.

Comment: The question seems to make no sense.

Comment: The way it is written, I agree that it makes no sense.  "*The number 2*" is not an element of your relation under the usual interpretation of what sort of object "*the number 2*" is.  It is possible they intend to talk about "*The equivalence class of pairs of numbers such that the sum of the numbers in the pair is equal to 2*" which would be either $\{(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)\}$ if you do include zero or just $\{(1,1)\}$ if you did not.

Comment: I'm guessing that however the problem was originally stated, something has been lost in your restated problem. I would check carefully to see whether you have stated the original problem correctly.

Comment: Another possibility however is that your relation is written incorrectly and this was meant to be $(a,b)T(c,d)$ if $a+d = c+b$ instead... at which point this is the defining equivalence relation for what it means for two *integers* to be equal.  Here, "*the* **integer** *two*" is *defined* as the equivalence class of $(2,0)$, at which point there is no confusion or contradiction here.  Yes, you need to recognize the difference in how "*the natural number two*" and "*the integer two*" are formally defined and recognize which "*two*" they were talking about in the question.